# Linear differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the differential equation

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} -\frac{3y}{x} =x^3\cos(x) (x>0)$$

Find the general solution expressing $y$ explicitly as a function of $x$.

Comment: Use the integrating factor method.

Comment: the solution containes the Bessel function

Comment: sorry what i have wrote is not true, i have had $y''$ enstead of $y'$

Answer (score 1):

1. The general solution of the hom. equation $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} -\frac{3y}{x} =0$ is given by

$y_h(x)=cx^3$ ($c \in \mathbb R$).

2. A spcial solution $y_s$ of the inhom. eqaution you get from

$y_s(x)=C(x)x^3$. Determine the function $C$.

(Controll: $C(x)= \sin x$)

3. The solutions of $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} -\frac{3y}{x} =x^3\cos(x)$ are then given by

$y(x)=cx^3+x^3 \sin x$  ($c \in \mathbb R$).